# convert return object to json but only certain value pairs

Tags: javascript, json, object

Yes I know there are heaps of posts about converting objects to json but my question is more specific..

Say Im calling some data from an api and the response is an object that looks like this

```
{
    date: ...,
    value: ...,
    useless-info: ...,
    useless-info: ...
}
```

now I know I can do this `JSON.stringify(returnedobject);`

so I get the newly formed json..

```
{
   "date": ...,
   "value": ...,
   "useless-info": ...,
   "useless-info": ...
}
```

now all I want in my newly formed json to be the `"date"` and `"value"` and remove the `useless-info` is this even possible?

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `newObject = { date: oldObject.date, value: oldObject.value }` ?

Comment: You could use `delete` before you `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: I added answer, hope it will work as per the expectation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create a new object with the data you want, or delete the fields you don't need:

```
const someReturn = {
  date: ...,
  value: ...,
  badstuff: ...
}

const goodObj = {
  date: someReturn.date,
  value: someReturn.value
}
```

Or to delete fields you can just call `delete someReturn.badstuff`

Answer (score 2):

**Working Demo**

```js
var jsonObj = {
   "date": "",
   "value": "",
   "useless-info": "",
   "useless-info": ""
};

delete jsonObj["useless-info"];

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

console.log(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) has a `replacer` `param` that can be used to limit `output` to a `whitelisted` `array` of `keys` you want to keep.

```js
// Input.
const input = {
  date: new Date(),
  value: 8905934,
  useless: 'useless',
  extra: 'extra'
}

// Output.
const output = JSON.stringify(input, ['date', 'value'])

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const oldJson = {
   "date": ...,
   "value": ...,
   "useless-info": ...,
   "useless-info": ...
}

const newJson = {
   "date" : oldJson.date,
   "value": oldJson.value 
}
```

Comment: glad I cloud help!